# How to display the latest news and blog posts in a front page using wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wordpress to create my own website. On the front page I want to dispaly the two latest blog posts and the two latest news article.
An example of text to display is like that:

```
    <div class="blog_bloc">
<span class="Title_post">Title</span>
<p class="text_post">blog post text  text text text text</p>
<button id="read" >
Read more
</button><br><br>
<span class="Title_post">Title</span>
<p class="text_post">blog post text  text text text text</p>
<button id="read" >
Read more
</button>
</div>
```

I found some plugins in wordpress for creating blog page and news page.Now I want to display the latest posts or articles from the blog page or news page to put it automatically in the front page.Is there any plugin to add in my template to scrap the latest articles and put them into the front page automatically?

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: I found a file posts page (home.php) of the template and I tried to followed it to display the title and the text of the article but no vain.

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest posts use this php function:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'include' => '',
    'exclude' => '',
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' =>'',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private',
    'suppress_filters' => true
);

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );
?>
```

This will return an array which you then can loop through to display the two latest posts.

An **example script** would look like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 2,
);

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );


foreach ($recent_posts as $post ) {

?>

<div class="blog_bloc">
    <span class="Title_post"><?php echo $post["post_title"]; ?></span>
    <button id="read" >
    Read more
    </button>
</div>

<?php

}

wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Comment: Have I put this program in a html page?

Comment: You will need to use a php page for dynamic content

Comment: The problem that wordpress uses some files and functions to display the posts and I didn't find how to use the code to display what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It will normally show five posts in homepage or anywhere.

```
// Define our WP Query Parameters
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?>

// Start our WP Query
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

// Display the Post Title with Hyperlink
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

// Display the Post Excerpt
<?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>

// Repeat the process and reset once it hits the limit
<?php 
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Use your own css.